# Refactoring Rails 3 Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this in my routes:

```
get '/boutique/new' => 'stores#new', :as => :new_store, :constraints => { :id => /[a-z0-9_-]/ } 
post '/boutique' => 'stores#create', :as => :create_store, :constraints => { :id => /[a-z0-9_-]/ }
get '/:shortname' => 'stores#show', :as => :store, :constraints => { :id => /[a-z0-9_-]/ }
get '/:shortname/edit' => 'stores#edit', :as => :edit_store, :constraints => { :id => /[a-z0-9_-]/ }
put '/:shortname' => 'stores#update', :as => :update_store, :constraints => { :id => /[a-z0-9_-]/ }
delete '/:shortname' => 'stores#delete', :as => :destroy_store, :constraints => { :id => /[a-z0-9_-]/ }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do the same? It doesn't look any elegant and even less if I add some more controls/actions to it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option would be to stick to [the standard resource routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). If anyone else ever needs to work on the application you're building, they'll thank you.

That said, if you really need this routing setup (for whatever reason), try the following:

```
controller :stores do
  constraints :id => /[a-z0-9_-]/ do
    get    '/boutique/new'    => :new,    :as => :new_store
    post   '/boutique'        => :create, :as => :create_store
    get    '/:shortname'      => :show,   :as => :store
    get    '/:shortname/edit' => :edit,   :as => :edit_store
    put    '/:shortname'      => :update, :as => :update_store
    delete '/:shortname'      => :delete, :as => :destroy_store
  end
end
```

I haven't actually tested it, but that should work fine.